# Lost at sea, I'm out of this world

Tags: riddle

At first, I'm hazy
With a switch, I'm explosive
Lost at sea, I'm out of this world
Without you, I'll be taught

What am I?

Comment: Amazing as usual :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think at first you are

> UNCLEAR - this is hazy

With a switch, I'm explosive

> NUCLEAR - switched N and U

Lost at sea, I'm out of this world

> UNREAL - lost C and anagrammed

Without you, I'll be taught

> LEARN - now removed U and anagrammed.